# Compare two dictionaries are identical and print key and value that are not matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am working on migration of database. I have source and target list of tables and row count stored in a dictionary. I need to compare both the dictionaries to find out if tables and data are migrated successfully

Code snipped below

```
sourceRowData = {'table1': 5, 'table2': 10, 'table3': 20, 'table4': 50}
targetRowData = {'table1': 5, 'table2': 10, 'table3': 8}
results = {}

# Compare keys
if set(sourceRowData.keys()) == set(targetRowData.keys()):
    for key in sourceRowData.keys():
        # Compare Values
        if sourceRowData[key] != targetRowData[key]:
           print ("Row count for table {} do not match".format(key))
           results["Table Row Count"] = "Failed"
        else:
           results["Table Row Count"] = "Pass"
else:
   results["Table Row Count"] = "Failed"
   # Display which table is missing based on the missing key
   for key, value in sourceRowData.items():
       if not key in targetRowData.keys():
          print ("Table {} not found in target database {}".format(key, targetDatabase))
```

I want to compare both key and respective values. If value (row count) do not match, then I want to display which table and row count do not match.

My code prints the message for each missing table, Instead I want to display row count not matching once and then print each table that count do not match to the console. Same as I did in case of comparing keys

My results dictionary, that contains the validation report keeps updating for every record which is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
sourceRowData = {'table1': 5, 'table2': 10, 'table3': 20, 'table4': 50}
targetRowData = {'table1': 5, 'table2': 10, 'table3': 8}


for key, v in sourceRowData.items():
    if key not in targetRowData:   #Check if table in targetRowData
        print ("Table {} not found in target database {}".format(key, "targetDatabase"))
    else:
        if v != targetRowData[key]:  #Check for count mismatch
            print("Failed: Table Row Count mismatch {}".format(key))
```

**Output:**

```
Failed: Table Row Count mismatch table3
Table table4 not found in target database targetDatabase
```

Comment: Please accept ans(tick symbol) if it solved your problem. Thanks